# creating buttons for dashboard, problems with onClick, maybe better solution?

Tags: java, android, layout, button

I am currently implementing my dashboard. My current solution for buttons is this:

```
<LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="33"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:background="@drawable/button_frame"
                        android:id="@+id/viewAddItemBtn"
                        android:onClick="BtnListener"
                        >
                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/addbutton"

                        />
                    <TextView 
                        android:text="Add Item"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        />
                        </LinearLayout>
```

However, I now have some problems with 1. the "clickability" and the states (focused/pressed/normal).
As you might guess out of my code: If i click on the "ImageButton" (which could basically be a imageview too on solution) it does nothing. (because onClick is not assigned, I thought it would inherit the attribute from its overall LinearLayout). Second thing is, if I make the "ImageButton" Clickable too, i guess the states won't be called, am I right here?

is there any better solutions for my design?
little demo-picture on how the button should look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSBk5.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do not you add the onClick property for all of the components:

```
<LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="33"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:background="@drawable/button_frame"
                        android:id="@+id/viewAddItemBtn"
                        android:onClick="BtnListener"
                        >
                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/addbutton"
                        android:onClick="BtnListener"

                        />
                    <TextView 
                        android:text="Add Item"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:onClick="BtnListener"
                        />
                        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: with this the different states
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame_pressed"
    android:state_pressed="true" />
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame_focused"
    android:state_focused="true" />
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame" />
</selector>`
don't get applied